# How to get the referring filename from a request in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, header, referer

I'm building the finishing touches on the registration aspect of my web application and am scratching my head on how I'm going to display a "success" message.

I've decided that I will redirect using:

```
header("Location: account.php", true, 303);
```

Once I've done that, I've decided to check the referring filename (and GET variable) to make sure it came from "account.php?action=processregister".

I'm wondering, how might I write code to retrieve the filename (and variables) that processed the redirect?

If you require more information, such as code, feel free to ask.

**UPDATE**

Found this after some digging on Google, could be useful to other askers: https://github.com/plasticbrain/PHP-Flash-Messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the refferer
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` from here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

For your question, i think you need to store some data in $_SESSION.

For example, `$_SESSION['flash-message'] = 'Registration done successefull!'`;

Comment: Thank you, however $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; returns something like "http://domain.tld/dir/dir2/filename.php", which is good, however what I need is the GET variables also (e.g. the ?action=thisorthat)